# How to add nested class to hover the menu

Tags: php, html, css

i would like menu to hover for the current page .
so i added the code below to call the jokesmenu >ul> li > a:hover when current page is opened the menu shouldhilight.But how to hover the current page with this css

```
            <li class=" <?php $jokes_ur="http://www.domain.com/jokes/";
    $url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    if ($jokes_ur==$url){
echo "jokesmenu" 
    }       
    ?>
"><a href="http://www.domain.com/jokes/">jokes<span>jokes</span></a></li>


.jokesmenu >ul> li > a:hover {
 background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(69, 199, 235), rgb(38, 152, 219));background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(69, 199, 235), rgb(38, 152, 219));
background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, rgb(69, 199, 235), rgb(38, 152, 219));background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top, rgb(69, 199, 235), rgb(38, 152, 219));
background-image:linear-gradient(top, rgb(69, 199, 235), rgb(38, 152, 219));filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,StartColorStr='#45c7eb', EndColorStr='#2698db');
color:#fff;list-style:none;text-decoration:none;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You want it to have the same look as hovered even when it isnt hovered to show that its the current page right? So firstly, you’ve added the class to the `li` so your css should read

```
.jokesmenu a, ul> li > a:hover { ... }
```

This way your hover still works and also if the li has `.jokesmenu` then it highlights that too.

Comment: @ADHI Is the php outputting the class on the `li`? you did want to apply the css to the `a` right?